# Google Tag Manager for cordova

Tags: cordova, google-tag-manager

I'm working on cordova application and i want to use Google Tag Manager within.
I found this plugin:
[cordova-plugin-tag-manager](https://github.com/kraihn/cordova-plugin-tag-manager) 
but it looks like it only offers tracking features (i've checked source code and it is calling some google analytics stuff).

But i want to also use non-standard tags (let's say display some popup using js).
I think it's impossible with this plugin, am i right?

And if yes, did anyone try to use 'web' version of embedding google tags?
For me it does not work, i'm getting error: 
`GET file://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXX net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the plugin you mentioned. I don't think what you're looking to do with the plugin is impossible. Google Tag Manager really only offers two types of tracking, pageview and events. In your case, I imagine you would want to track the event of clicking on the item that opens the popup. You can do this by attaching a call to tagManager.trackEvent to the button.

This description by Google about [Analytic Events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en) can help you determine how to specify the event type for a popup.

Comment: Hmm. It look's like i have some homework to do with getting to know about Google Tag Manager. 
Thank you for your answer, i will go back to plugin and try again.